# Piwik: Servername changes depending on network

Tags: javascript, networking, matomo

I run Piwik webanalytics on site which has different domain name/address depending on which network the user is viewing the site. Also, the name/address of Piwik server changes depending on the network.

Lets say user a is on network aa, and the Piwik server address on that network is:
192.168.0.1
User b is on network bb, and there the address of the same server is:
192.168.0.2

How can I make Piwik work on both networks? Using dns is not an option.
There seems to be no solution to this in Piwik options. Is there any other way to do this?

Here's the part of the tracking script, which defines the server address:

```
(function() {
var u="//192.168.0.1/piwik/";
_paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
_paq.push(['setSiteId', '2']);
var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution to this, but since it might come handy for others too, I decided to answer my own question.

The easies way to do this is to ad an if-statement to the function which defines the server address. The page domains in both aa and bb networks are different, so just find out in witch network the site was loaded and change the address acording to the network.

Let's say the site domain in network aa is: 192.168.0.3 and in bb network the site domain is 192.168.0.4

```
(function() {
if (window.location.hostname === "192.168.0.3")
{var u="//192.168.0.1/piwik/"}
else {
var u="//192.168.0.2/piwik/";
}
_paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
_paq.push(['setSiteId', '2']);
var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
})();
```